# What is difference between "options and error code" in jshint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I had confusion between options and error/warning code in jshint.

curly : true

or

W116

How to identify "curly options" belongs to  W116 Code?

```
 while(true)
            alert("ok");
```

demo.js: line 3, col 5, Expected '{' and instead saw 'alert'.(W116)

Please let me know, If my question is not clear.

Comment: The options there are generally broad and cover a variety of cases, while the specific warning codes are only for very specific cases, which can be sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

And if you really want to know what error codes belong to what options, I guess you'll have to dive in the source code [here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/2.1.4/src/stable/jshint.js#L1789)..

But usually the documentation should be enough, [curly option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#curly):

> This option requires you to always put curly braces around blocks in
>   loops and conditionals. JavaScript allows you to omit curly braces
>   when the block consists of only one statement, for example:

```
while (day)
    shuffle();
```

> However, in some circumstances, it can lead
>   to bugs (you'd think that sleep() is a part of the loop while in
>   reality it is not):

```
while (day)
    shuffle();
    sleep();
```

Also, if sometimes you wonder what an error code corresponds to, check this file:

[messages.js](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/2.1.4/src/shared/messages.js)

So in your case:

[messages.js#L189](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/2.1.4/src/shared/messages.js#L189)